# Is there a way to break/split carousel item in 3 cards each row in angular 8?

Tags: angular

How do I split json response data in 3 items per row and display it in carousel items in angular 8? Do I need to changes in .ts file ? (I'm still in learning stage in angular)

Code in app.component.html - I have used bootstrap carousel so no component.ts code is there

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="dataInfo">
      <h2>Information</h2>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let i of games">
                <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid"
                    src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg" width="100"
                    height="100" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{i.name}}</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                      additional content. This content is a little
                      bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm getting the output as below image when I iterate `*ngFor ="let i of games"` and display as list instead horizontal scrollable.

[image]

But the required output should be scrollable,
[image]

Comment: Share your code on stackblitz.

Comment: Ok reference code I took from here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaevix
I will try to code it in stackblitz and share it ..meanwhile you can go through and in that code If we get the data from server or json then how do i split it in 3 items per row?